# Stream a video file over http with Spark Java

Tags: java, rest, jersey, mime-types, spark-java

I'm trying to stream a video file over rest, I'm trying to implement something similar to Jersey like this:

```
      ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok(out.toByteArray());
      builder.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fields.get("filename"));
      response = builder.build();
    } else {
      response = Response.status(404).
          entity(" Unable to get file with ID: " + id).
          type("text/plain").
          build();
    }

    return response;
  }
```

Here is what I have for file upload and download/streaming (download semi-works, the file size is correct by corrupted):

I really need help with this everyone, thanks

**UPDATE**

changed:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out =  new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

to:

```
ServletOutputStream out = res.raw().getOutputStream();
```

**UPDATE 2**
Ok, I finally got it working, and the video plays in the browser, but now getting a Jetty `io.EofException`, I closed the stream but still, must be something simple.

Below are both the before and after:

and downloading the file from the browser works, but how can I stream it directly in the browser?

**BEFORE(didn't work)**

```
    //download a video/ trying to stream it right in the browser if possible
    get("/post/:id", (req, res ) -> {

            res.raw().setContentType("application/octet-stream");

            String id = req.params(":id");

            ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId(id);
            BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();

            query.put("_id", objectId);
            //DBObject video = collection.findOne(query);

            GridFS gridfile = new GridFS(db, "videos");
            GridFSDBFile gridFSDBFile = gridfile.findOne(query);
            res.raw().setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + gridFSDBFile.getFilename());

            InputStream inputStream = gridFSDBFile.getInputStream();

             ServletOutputStream out = res.raw().getOutputStream();
            // ByteArrayOutputStream out =  new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int data = inputStream.read();
            while (data >= 0) {
                out.write((char) data);
                data = inputStream.read();
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            return out;
        });
```

**AFTER (This works perfectly, but getting the end of file exception):**

```
   get("/post/:id", (req, res ) -> {
            //what's the difference between these 2?
            res.raw().setContentType("video/mp4");
            res.type("video/mp4");

            String id = req.params(":id");

            ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId(id);
            BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();

            query.put("_id", objectId);
            GridFS gridfile = new GridFS(db, "videos");
            GridFSDBFile gridFSDBFile = gridfile.findOne(query);

            res.raw().setContentLengthLong(gridFSDBFile.getLength());
            InputStream inputStream = gridFSDBFile.getInputStream();

            ServletOutputStream out = res.raw().getOutputStream();

            int data = inputStream.read();
            while (data >= 0) {
                gridFSDBFile.writeTo(out);
                data = inputStream.read();
            }

           // out.flush();
           out.close();

           return 200;

        });
```

**Upload:**

```
 post("/postvideo/:username", (req, res) -> {
            MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement =
                    new MultipartConfigElement("/tmp");
            req.raw().
                    setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.multipartConfig",
                            multipartConfigElement);
            String username = req.params(":username");
            double[] location =
                    new double[2];
            double lattitude =
                    Double.parseDouble(req.queryParams("lat"));
            double longitude =
                    Double.parseDouble(req.queryParams("lon"));
            location[0] = lattitude;
            location[1] = longitude;

            InputStream inputStream = req.raw().getPart("file").getInputStream();;

            Part uploadedFile = req.raw().getPart("file");
            // File file = new File(uploadedFile.getName());
            GridFS gridFS = new GridFS(db, "videos");

            GridFSInputFile gfsFile = gridFS.createFile(inputStream);

            gfsFile.put("location", location);
            gfsFile.put("username", username);
            gfsFile.put("contentType", req.raw().getContentType());
            gfsFile.put("filename", uploadedFile.getSubmittedFileName());
            collection.insert(gfsFile);

            gfsFile.save();
            return 201;
        });
```

Comment: Sorry to be the nitpicker but I cringed when I saw the way you phrased the question. You can't stream a video over an architectural style.

Comment: @toniedzwiedz ??? ok, don't really know what you mean. Anyway, I improved the hell out of my solution and works perfectly. Maybe I phrased it wrong but your comment is actually useless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the method that works. I will be uploading a solution that let's you skip to sections of the video as well, piece of cake ;)

```
  get("/post/:id", (req, res ) -> {
        //what's the difference between these 2?
        res.raw().setContentType("video/mp4");
        res.type("video/mp4");

        String id = req.params(":id");

        ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId(id);
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();

        query.put("_id", objectId);
        GridFS gridfile = new GridFS(db, "videos");
        GridFSDBFile gridFSDBFile = gridfile.findOne(query);

        res.raw().setContentLengthLong(gridFSDBFile.getLength());
        InputStream inputStream = gridFSDBFile.getInputStream();

        ServletOutputStream out = res.raw().getOutputStream();

        int data = inputStream.read();
        while (data >= 0) {
            gridFSDBFile.writeTo(out);
            data = inputStream.read();
        }

       // out.flush();
       out.close();

       return 200;

    });
```

Comment: Hi @franklinexpress - I took a look at Sparkjava's github issues, and it seems that an approach that has an unbounded (unknown length) stream would not work? Is this right? My specific use case is proxying a live audio stream (e.g. `http://82.77.137.30:8557/;` )

Comment: yes it should work. I now have implemented that using a Servlet with seek functionality(Accept-Ranges) the seek part wouldn't work for unknown length but streaming should.

Comment: oh sweet. So, I would just not set the length. Thank you.